# Ruby on Rails model errors in API with full hash instead of dot notation with accepts nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am running Rails 7 in API mode and I want to return the errors as a full object instead of one with dot notation strings. Lets say the Address accepts nested attributes for phone_number.

Here is my code as is:

```
def create
  @address = Address.new(address_params)
  if @address.save
    render json: @address, status: :created
  else
    render json: {errors: @address.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

On an invalid phone number it returns

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "phone_number.number": "is not a valid number"
  }
}
```

what is the best way to have it return

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "phone_number": {
      "number": "is not a valid number"
    }
  }
}
```

I could parse these out on the client side, but this seems like it would be better suited to handle on the server.

Thanks

Comment: Is that some phone number gem or custom type that you're using?

Comment: It is a model called PhoneNumber that utilizes 'phony_rails' to normalize the numbers.

Comment: Ah ok, so no - that's the hardcoded way that Rails presents errors within associated objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I have gotten. I am not a fan of this solution as it feels like there should be an option that I can pass to do this for me.

```rb
# Convert a hash that may have flat keys with dots into a nested hash.
  # This is useful because nested attributes return as dot notation and that creates
  # redundant code on the client that would have to handle this.
  # @param hash [Hash] the hash to convert.
  # @return [Hash] the nested hash.
  def flat_keys_to_nested(hash)
    hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), all|
      key_parts = key.to_s.split('.').map!(&:to_sym)
      leaf = key_parts[0...-1].inject(all) { |h, k| h[k] ||= {} }
      leaf[key_parts.last] = value
    end
  end

  def create
    @address = Address.new(address_params)
    if @address.save
      render json: @address, status: :created
    else
      render json: {errors: flat_keys_to_nested(@address.errors.to_hash)}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

This dumps the errors to a hash, and uses some unknown code from the internet that takes dot notation and makes them into a full hash.